# dropdown css menu converted to rtl from ltr

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, right-to-left

I have a menu which is ltr:
[image]
Which I converted to rtl:
[image]

Now, I want this dropdown button appear before the link "PRODUCT" and the 2 number box appear, where I made a green box.

Comment: Can you add this in jsfiddle so that we can work that out?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m5sn8voj/
Check it out

Comment: Showing some errors in console.

Comment: now check it out, I attached Jquery lib.
https://jsfiddle.net/m5sn8voj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `rtl` style for the menu - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/m5sn8voj/2/

You can use `rtl` converting tools available online - https://cssjanus.github.io/.  Paste the css, and you will get the right-to-left css instantly.